# How to insert row with next id in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I'm using mysql 8 and I'm a big noob so be polite please, I have a table with only 2 columns, ID (Primary key, Not Null, Auto Increment, Unique) and Password (Not Null, Unique)

I'd like to have something like this:

```
+----+------------+
| id | Password   |
+----+------------+
| 1  | dsakjhsajs |
+----+------------+
| 2  | xczkcjhczx |
+----+------------+
| 3  | treiuytreu |
+----+------------+
```

Is it possible to INSERT a new password without specifying the id and let the db calculate the id?

Because if I use

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('anotherpassword')
```

I obviously get an error

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a noob. But equally, nothing wrong with spending 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the columns for which you will be inserting values:

```
INSERT into mytable (passwordcol) VALUES ('password1');
```

The word "password" is a keyword, so avoid that as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

[insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) has a syntax to specify columns:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(`Password`) VALUES ('anotherpassword')
```

ps. Don't store clear text passwords.

Comment: Thanks, so if I have a lot of columns I have to specify everyone except for the ID?

Comment: Anything that doesn't have a default value needs to be specified, and the number needs match to the number of values specified.

Comment: [examples on password storage](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/)